# ngx-translate getBrowserLang returns 'en' all the time

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I'm using ngx-translate. I changed my OS language to german, but still when I print out `this.translate.getBrowserLang()` it returns 'en'.

```
protected myMethod() {
    this.translate.setDefaultLang( 'en' );
    this.translate.use( 'de' );
    console.log( 'Browser Lang', this.translate.getBrowserLang());
}
```

but when I use 
`console.log( 'Browser Lang', navigator.language)` it prints 'de' as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Also is there a way to automatically detect and switch the language in ngx-translate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.getBrowserLang()` returns the FIRST default browser language.

And  `navigator.language` return the current user navigator language preference.

So use `navigator.language` is the best way to detect user current language

Comment: navigator. language comes undefined